# Intellij Plugin - can i read a maven pom file?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

With intellij plugins I have access to PsiFiles, which let me read the contents of a, say, java file. They provide, in effect, a tree-like structure for examining a file, which is great.

Is there some way to do the same - or similar - with a pom.xml file? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Yes it is also a psi file and has the same PSI structure as an xml file. See here [How do I find a file if I know its name but don’t know the path](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/psi_cookbook.html#how-do-i-find-a-file-if-i-know-its-name-but-dont-know-the-path) and the rest of IntelliJ SDK documentation about [PSI files](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/psi_files.html)

Comment: @Andrey thanks! The intellij documentation is atrocious - a great reference material maybe, but it's a struggle to learn from. I stumbled on this - https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/webinar-recording-live-coding-a-plugin-from-scratch/ - which is an amazing resource. Do you know of any other tutorials for plugin development?

Comment: Tutorial for what exactly? There is e.g. [getting started](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html) or step by step instructions on how to add [custom language support](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html) into editor.

Comment: @Andrey yeh, i've seen that, it's not great. The video i linked is excellent, it just explains how to do something and captures for the most part how everything fits together. I find otherwise the intellij tutorials breeze past key concepts, so you need to already have a great understanding to follow the tutorials, and at that level of understanding, the tutorials no longer add real value...

Comment: @Andrey i suppose for me any explanatory tutorial should really assume no major prior knowledge, whereas the intellij tutorials seem to be written for the person who "gets" how their plugin framework works